# regex to capture only number at the end

Tags: regex

I've some sample text as below.

```
this is 1989 representing text 245
this is sample text 235
this is 234 sample text with comma seperator 345,756
```

here i need a `regex` to get number only at the end, I've tried the below

[(0-9)+]

but this is capturing all the numbers, but only the number after the text ends needs to be captured.

The captured values should be

```
245
235
345,756
```

please let me know how can i do this.

Thanks

Comment: Other than `,` what else is allowed?

Comment: Hi @sshashank124, other than `,` there would be `&#emdash;`, `&#endash;`, `-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\d+(?=[-, \d]*$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oK9uT5)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it as:

```
/[\d,]+$/mg
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/gI4kS4)

To allow more characters, just add them to the character class:

```
/[\d,.-_]+$/mg
```

or if you want, simply allow everything *except* non accented letters:

```
/[^a-zA-Z]+$/mg
```

Comment: thanks dude, this works awesome, but the numbers should be captured, not the `,` and so on symbols

Comment: @user2423959, So basically, you want to match any number that is _not_ followed by a letter? Because how else am I supposed to know which numbers to capture from this: `'Hello 123 world 456 - 789'`

Comment: the last numbers after the text, here in the example you gave, `456 and 789` needs to be captured

Comment: @user2423959, Here's a start. It is hard to get exactly as you specified: http://regex101.com/r/bN9tJ1

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this which is simple to read :
`^.*[0-9]+$`

`^.*` Begins with whatever you want of whatever length
`[0-9]+$` Ends with at least one number (or more)

If you wish only to recover the numbers and not the lines that correspond to your request :
`[0-9]+$`

And here we can add the complexity of recovering the comma :
`[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?$`

Comment: You are confusing character class and multiple digits. Remove the square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this much simpler ?

Allowed: only digits

```
\d+$
```

Allowed: digits, comma, dashes

```
[\d,-]+$
```

Allowed: digits, dashes

```
[\d-]+$
```

Comment: It won't capture `345` in `this is 234 sample text with comma seperator 345,756`.

Comment: ok.. I missed that part of the question. In that case, `[\d,-]+$` would do. Other characters can be added as necessary. Just edited my answer above.

Comment: this is simple, but even the comma is getting captured i don't want the comma, thanks

Comment: Ok.. then the original answer was correct. IN that case Use `\d+$` to capture only digits, or `[\d-]+$` to capture digits with dashes allowed in between. I just updated my reply above.